# Как ajax -ом взять товар из бд вместо php скрипта?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Всем привет, такая ситуация, сделал я MVC-архитектуру по курсу,все работает нормально, товар выводится в общем все ок, дело в том что мне нужно вывести весть товар на страницу, (а товара у меня немного), чтобы потом фильтровать его по клику на чекбоксы, и проблема в том что это MVC, сколько искал я инфу по этой теме, но без результатов, (возможно не правильно искал незнаю) единственное что нашел хоть более понятное, это было то что нужно ajax-ом отправить запрос к контроллеру и им выводит товар на страницу, но больше я никак не нашел инфу по этой теме, если искать по такому запросу AJAX запрос к контроллеру то большинство ссылок связаны с Yii фреймворком, и хотелось бы если вы меня поняли подсказали как мне дальше двигаться, извините за столь длинный вопрос) ?

Задача в том чтобы при клике на чекбокс, получать товар, или же фильтровать, на данный момент на сайте есть товар типа последние или новинки и все, и чекбосы с наименованиями, и чтобы при клике на чекбокс получить соответствующий товар и вывести его в блоке вместо новинок, как мне поступить что нужно для этого сделать

```
class Product
{
    const SHOW_BY_DEFAULT = 10;

    /**
     *
     */

    public static function getLatestProducts($count = self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT)
    {
        $count = intval($count);

        $db = Db::getConnection();

        $productsList = array();

        $result = $db->query('SELECT id, name, price, image, is_new, data_id, description FROM product '
                . 'WHERE status = "1"'
                . 'ORDER BY id DESC '
                . 'LIMIT ' . $count);

        $i = 0;

        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $productsList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $productsList[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $productsList[$i]['image'] = $row['image'];
            $productsList[$i]['price'] = $row['price'];
            $productsList[$i]['is_new'] = $row['is_new'];
            $productsList[$i]['data_id'] = $row['data_id'];


            $productsList[$i]['description'] = $row['description'];

            $i++;
        }

        return $productsList;

    }
/**
 * 
 */

public static function getProductsListByCategory($categoryId = false, $page = 1)
{
    if ($categoryId) {

        $page = intval($page);            
        $offset = ($page - 1) * self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT;

        $db = Db::getConnection();            
        $products = array();
        $result = $db->query("SELECT id, name, price, image, is_new, description  FROM product "
                . "WHERE status = '1' AND category_id = '$categoryId' "
                . "ORDER BY id ASC "                
                . "LIMIT ".self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT
                . ' OFFSET '. $offset);

        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $products[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $products[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $products[$i]['image'] = $row['image'];
            $products[$i]['price'] = $row['price'];
            $products[$i]['is_new'] = $row['is_new'];
            $products[$i]['description'] = $row['description'];
            $i++;
        }

        return $products;       
    }
}



}
```

Вот файл SiteController

```
include_once ROOT . '/models/Category.php';
include_once ROOT . '/models/Product.php';

class SiteController
{

public function actionIndex()
{

    $categories = array();
    $categories = Category::getCategoriesList();

    $latestProducts = Product::getLatestProducts(20);

    require_once(ROOT . '/views/site/index.php');

    return true;
}
```

}

Вот ajax запрос, ну это так, мои попытки

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
$('input').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/models/fetch_data.php",
        type: 'POST', 
        success: function(response){ 
            $('.product-list').append(response); 
        }
    })
});
```

});

не знаю что еще нужно показать Буду благодарен за совет

Comment: Аяксом невозможно обратиться к БД напрямую. Надо обращаться к РНР скрипту. Как именно работает скрипт, через MVC, или нет - без разницы. Принцип всегда один и тот же. Надо просто сделать РНР скрипт который возвращает нужные данные, и запросить его аяксом

Comment: @Ипатьев получается мне нужно запросить файл Product.php ? в этом файле у меня запрашивает данные из базы и вывожу циклом, в index.php

Comment: В архитектуре MVC надо запрашивать раут, коорый вызывает контроллер. Ну то есть все то же самое что и без аякс. Для сервера все запросы одинаковые, что аяксом что без.